# Lighthouse Synced but Blocks Empty

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, lighthouse

I have setup geth and lighthouse on sepolia.

Geth is fully synced and says `Beacon client online, but no consensus updates received in a while. Please fix your beacon client to follow the chain!`

Lighthouse starts fine. Is listening to 8551 port as evidenced through sof -i :8551

Geth is also having txpool and block transaction, but still lighthouse blocks are empty:

```
slot: 4398150, block:    …  empty, epoch: 137442, finalized_epoch: 132606, finalized_root: 0x167b…3004, exec_hash: 0x7d4b…6bc4 (verified), peers: 6, service: slot_notifier
```

I know for sure tx are there as I can see on etherscan sepolia. What could be wrong? I have spent a day headbanging against this. Any help is deeply appreciated!

These are geth startup logs:

```
geth --sepolia --datadir geth-tutorial --authrpc.addr localhost --authrpc.port 8551 --authrpc.vhosts localhost --authrpc.jwtsecret geth-tutorial/jwtsecret --http --http.api eth,net --signer=geth-tutorial/clef/clef.ipc
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.307] Starting Geth on Sepolia testnet...
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.314] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 total=50
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.317] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.318] Using external signer                    url=geth-tutorial/clef/clef.ipc
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.327] Set global gas cap                       cap=50,000,000
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.327] Initializing the KZG library             backend=gokzg
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.484] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=154.00MiB dirty=256.00MiB
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.510] Using pebble as the backing database
INFO [02-21|11:33:59.513] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/geth-tutorial/geth/chaindata cache=512.00MiB handles=524,288
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.192] Opened ancient database                  database=/root/geth-tutorial/geth/chaindata/ancient/chain readonly=false
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.237] State scheme set to already existing     scheme=hash
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.496] Initialising Ethereum protocol           network=11,155,111 dbversion=8
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.500]
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.501] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.502] Chain ID:  11155111 (sepolia)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516] Consensus: Beacon (proof-of-stake), merged from Ethash (proof-of-work)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516] Pre-Merge hard forks (block based):
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Homestead:                   #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/homestead.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Tangerine Whistle (EIP 150): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/tangerine-whistle.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Spurious Dragon/1 (EIP 155): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Spurious Dragon/2 (EIP 158): #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Byzantium:                   #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/byzantium.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Constantinople:              #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/constantinople.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Petersburg:                  #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/petersburg.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Istanbul:                    #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/istanbul.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Muir Glacier:                #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/muir-glacier.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Berlin:                      #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/berlin.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - London:                      #0        (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516] Merge configured:
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Hard-fork specification:    https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/paris.md
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Network known to be merged: true
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Total terminal difficulty:  17000000000000000
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Merge netsplit block:       #1735371
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516] Post-Merge hard forks (timestamp based):
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Shanghai:                    @1677557088 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/shanghai.md)
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]  - Cancun:                      @1706655072
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516] ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.516]
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.538] Loaded most recent local block           number=5,187,022 hash=7d4b51..626bc4 td=17,000,018,015,853,232 age=3w11h43m
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.549] Loaded most recent local finalized block number=5,186,963 hash=ab3833..a4b9ce td=17,000,018,015,853,232 age=3w11h55m
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.549] Loaded last snap-sync pivot marker       number=5,186,958
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.564] Initialized transaction indexer          range="last 2350000 blocks"
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.565] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.565] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
WARN [02-21|11:34:01.606] Switch sync mode from snap sync to full sync reason="snap sync complete"
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.606] Chain post-merge, sync via beacon client
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.606] Gasprice oracle is ignoring threshold set threshold=2
WARN [02-21|11:34:01.613] Engine API enabled                       protocol=eth
INFO [02-21|11:34:01.613] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.13.12-stable-02eb36af/linux-amd64/go1.21.6
INFO [02-21|11:34:02.114] New local node record                    seq=1,708,291,908,155 id=6dfaa36b025d04d0 ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [02-21|11:34:02.118] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://ad60eb5c55d683bf56f818e3ad75124d84ffa2e758f7e2f543c7a750ce3e22aeb73afea3ff7c8424b4270c8d8133165d07f61db20c770905d842318f530851f2@127.0.0.1:30303
INFO [02-21|11:34:02.143] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/root/geth-tutorial/geth.ipc
INFO [02-21|11:34:02.143] Loaded JWT secret file                   path=geth-tutorial/jwtsecret crc32=0xdb370801
INFO [02-21|11:34:02.191] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8545 auth=false prefix= cors= vhosts=localhost
INFO [02-21|11:34:02.196] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://127.0.0.1:8551
INFO [02-21|11:34:02.196] HTTP server started                      endpoint=127.0.0.1:8551 auth=true  prefix= cors=localhost vhosts=localhost
WARN [02-21|11:34:02.196] Failed to open wallet                    url=extapi://geth-tutorial/clef/cle.. err="operation not supported on external signers"
INFO [02-21|11:34:05.204] New local node record                    seq=1,708,291,908,156 id=6dfaa36b025d04d0 ip=109.199.101.72 udp=30303 tcp=30303
```

These are lighthouse startup logs:

```
root@vmi1667389:~# lighthouse bn --network sepolia --execution-endpoint http://localhost:8551 --execution-jwt geth-tutorial/jwtsecret --checkpoint-sync-url https://beaconstate-sepolia.chainsafe.io --disable-deposit-contract-sync
Feb 21 10:36:15.495 INFO Logging to file                         path: "/root/.lighthouse/sepolia/beacon/logs/beacon.log"
Feb 21 10:36:15.513 INFO Lighthouse started                      version: Lighthouse/v4.0.1-a53830f
Feb 21 10:36:15.513 INFO Configured for network                  name: sepolia
Feb 21 10:36:15.526 INFO Data directory initialised              datadir: /root/.lighthouse/sepolia
Feb 21 10:36:15.526 INFO Deposit contract                        address: 0x7f02c3e3c98b133055b8b348b2ac625669ed295d, deploy_block: 1273020
Feb 21 10:36:15.639 INFO Hot-Cold DB initialized                 split_state: 0xee251812063c13cfc23bb86ac86615b059a7db6fabaf4ea140b1fb66c169de87, split_slot: 4243392, service: freezer_db
Feb 21 10:36:15.730 INFO Refusing to checkpoint sync             msg: database already exists, use --purge-db to force checkpoint sync, service: beacon
Feb 21 10:36:15.730 INFO Starting beacon chain                   method: resume, service: beacon
Feb 21 10:36:15.970 INFO Block production disabled               reason: no eth1 backend configured
Feb 21 10:36:16.052 INFO Beacon chain initialized                head_slot: 4243455, head_block: 0x7cd5…f93d, head_state: 0xd60b…291d, service: beacon
Feb 21 10:36:16.052 INFO Timer service started                   service: node_timer
Feb 21 10:36:16.057 INFO UPnP Attempting to initialise routes    service: UPnP
Feb 21 10:36:16.061 INFO ENR Initialised                         tcp4: None, udp4: Some(9000), ip4: Some(109.199.101.72), id: 0xecc3..57cd, seq: 2, enr: enr:-Ly4QNzxD_32YvGde403Qeca6WRfObwBeQR8U5eVVcYW3lkdOL6fTSq7GoCSsrmpbWgEp-kdCW45akZ2MPuFPPyk0yICh2F0dG5ldHOIAAAAAAAAAACEZXRoMpBH63KzkAAAcv__________gmlkgnY0gmlwhG3HZUiJc2VjcDI1NmsxoQOUjfoA25pRVsZWKC8WLUhQ0uJIYxASeQ4-Lmb_5EyezohzeW5jbmV0cwCDdGNwgiMog3VkcIIjKA, service: libp2p
Feb 21 10:36:16.070 INFO Libp2p Starting                         bandwidth_config: 3-Average, peer_id: 16Uiu2HAmNetFj4fUE62k1yDuVJrrNMhXsHFYSvVQRjMpMgeWKNLD, service: libp2p
Feb 21 10:36:16.070 INFO Listening established                   address: /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/9000/p2p/16Uiu2HAmNetFj4fUE62k1yDuVJrrNMhXsHFYSvVQRjMpMgeWKNLD, service: libp2p
Feb 21 10:36:16.096 INFO Execution payloads are pruned           service: freezer_db
Feb 21 10:36:16.134 INFO HTTP server is disabled
Feb 21 10:36:16.149 INFO Execution engine online                 service: exec
Feb 21 10:36:16.149 INFO Issuing forkchoiceUpdated               forkchoice_state: ForkchoiceState { head_block_hash: 0x7d4b51c0ffc01dc67d23beeb881312afcbea745f4cd7a1defb959a8331626bc4, safe_block_hash: 0xc59c383322993d1192557ffb8b5b6ac35e5f3eb7e611ed665765ed10401e8418, finalized_block_hash: 0xab383371f12923dc3a9c3c088196e4f61e274ef406fc309f20f7d74b4fa4b9ce }, service: exec
Feb 21 10:36:19.624 INFO Sync state updated                      new_state: Synced, old_state: Stalled, service: sync
Feb 21 10:36:19.624 INFO Subscribed to topics                    topics: ["/eth2/47eb72b3/bls_to_execution_change/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/sync_committee_contribution_and_proof/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/beacon_block/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/beacon_aggregate_and_proof/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/voluntary_exit/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/proposer_slashing/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/attester_slashing/ssz_snappy"], service: network
Feb 21 10:36:20.569 INFO Sync state updated                      new_state: Stalled, old_state: Synced, service: sync
Feb 21 10:36:23.798 INFO Sync state updated                      new_state: Synced, old_state: Stalled, service: sync
Feb 21 10:36:23.798 INFO Subscribed to topics                    topics: ["/eth2/47eb72b3/bls_to_execution_change/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/sync_committee_contribution_and_proof/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/beacon_block/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/beacon_aggregate_and_proof/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/voluntary_exit/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/proposer_slashing/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/attester_slashing/ssz_snappy"], service: network
Feb 21 10:36:23.959 INFO Sync state updated                      new_state: Stalled, old_state: Synced, service: sync
Feb 21 10:36:26.207 INFO UPnP not available                      error: IO error: Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11), service: UPnP
Feb 21 10:36:30.007 WARN Low peer count                          peer_count: 0, service: slot_notifier
Feb 21 10:36:30.007 INFO Searching for peers                     current_slot: 4398182, head_slot: 4243455, finalized_epoch: 132606, finalized_root: 0x167b…3004, peers: 0, service: slot_notifier
Feb 21 10:36:42.008 WARN Low peer count                          peer_count: 0, service: slot_notifier
Feb 21 10:36:42.063 INFO Searching for peers                     current_slot: 4398183, head_slot: 4243455, finalized_epoch: 132606, finalized_root: 0x167b…3004, peers: 0, service: slot_notifier
Feb 21 10:36:44.796 INFO Sync state updated                      new_state: Synced, old_state: Stalled, service: sync
Feb 21 10:36:44.796 INFO Subscribed to topics                    topics: ["/eth2/47eb72b3/bls_to_execution_change/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/sync_committee_contribution_and_proof/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/beacon_block/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/beacon_aggregate_and_proof/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/voluntary_exit/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/proposer_slashing/ssz_snappy", "/eth2/47eb72b3/attester_slashing/ssz_snappy"], service: network
Feb 21 10:36:54.000 INFO Synced                                  slot: 4398184, block:    …  empty, epoch: 137443, finalized_epoch: 132606, finalized_root: 0x167b…3004, exec_hash: 0x7d4b…6bc4 (verified), peers: 7, service: slot_notifier
```